# Access outer struct with the same name

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Look at my sample code

```
struct A
{
   int member;
};

int main()
{
   int A; //Line 1
   A b;   //Line 2 
   b.member = int(); //Line 3
}
```

Errors are

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:9: error: expected `;' before ‘b’
prog.cpp:9: warning: statement has no effect
prog.cpp:10: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
```

How to access structure A in second line ? Why do I get the error anyway?

Comment: You should always include the error you get in such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to remove the error in Line 2?

Use Elaborated Type Specifier, i.e instead of writing `A b;` write `struct A b;`.

> **3.4.4  Elaborated type specifiers**
>
> An elaborated-type-specifier may be used to refer to a previously declared class-name or enum-name **even though the name has been hidden by a non-type declaration (3.3.7)**.  The class-name or enum-name in the elaborated-type-specifier may either be a simple identifer or be a qualified-id.

---

> Why do I get the error anyway?

Because `A` outside main is hidden inside main after the definition of `int A`. The only way to access `struct A` is by using elaborated-type-specifier.

> **3.3.7  Name hiding**
>
> 2) A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of an object, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope.  If a class or enumeration name and an object, function, or enumerator are declared in the **same scope (in any order) with the same name**, the  class  or  enumeration  name  is  hidden wherever the object, function, or enumerator name is visible.